# GetHotelDescriptiveInfo Soap - 'SabreHeader/Service Missing or incomplete' Error

Tags: c#, soap, sabre

I am trying to work with the new GetHotelDescriptiveInfo Service and have created the message header object as I have created other v1 requests in the past without issue, but for this service when I execute it I get the following error response:

```
<ns4:ApplicationResults xmlns:ns4="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="NotProcessed">
    <ns4:Error type="Validation" timeStamp="2016-10-21T08:15:07.497-05:00">
        <ns4:SystemSpecificResults>
            <ns4:Message code="ERR.NGHP-CONTENT.CLIENT.INVALID_REQUEST">
                SabreHeader/Service missing or incomplete
            </ns4:Message>
        </ns4:SystemSpecificResults>
    </ns4:Error>
</ns4:ApplicationResults>
```

Here is the code used to create the MessageHeader object;

```
MessageHeader header = new MessageHeader();
header.ConversationId = this.Session.ConversationId;

From from = new From();
PartyId fromPartyId = new PartyId();
fromPartyId.Value = "WebServiceClient";
PartyId[] fromPartyIdArr = new PartyId[1];
fromPartyIdArr[0] = fromPartyId;
from.PartyId = fromPartyIdArr;
header.From = from;

To to = new To();
PartyId toPartyId = new PartyId();
toPartyId.Value = "WebServiceSupplier";
PartyId[] toPartyIdArr = new PartyId[1];
toPartyIdArr[0] = toPartyId;
to.PartyId = toPartyIdArr;
header.To = to;

header.CPAId = this.Session.PCC;
header.Action = "GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ";
header.Service = new Service();
header.Service.Value = "GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ";

MessageData msgData = new MessageData();
msgData.MessageId = String.Format("mid:{0}@clientofsabre.com1", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMDD-HHmmss-ffff"));
msgData.Timestamp = String.Format("{0}Z", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s"));
header.MessageData = msgData;
```

I'm not sure what I am missing in the header.  Whether it's a piece of information or I have the service value incorrect.  I have tried numerous variations of the service value with no success.  Has anyone come across this error before?

UPDATE:

Below is an example of the generated xml, sensitive data masked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmln s:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>WebServiceClient</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>WebServiceSupplier</Party Id>
            </To>
            <CPAId>XXXX</CPAId>
            <ConversationId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ConversationId>
            <Service>GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ</Service>
            <Action>GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>mid:201611DD-0934 50-6693@clientofsabre.com</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>2016-11-21T14:3 4:50Z</Timestamp>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <BinarySecurityToken>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/hotel/descriptiveinfo/v1">
            <HotelRefs>
                <HotelRef HotelCode="2355" />
                <HotelRef HotelCode="2356" />
            </HotelRefs>
            <DescriptiveInfoRef>
                <PropertyInfo>true</PropertyInfo>
                <LocationInfo>true</LocationInfo>
                <Amenities>true</Amenities>
                <Airports>true</Airports>
                <AcceptedCreditCards>false</AcceptedCreditCards>
            </DescriptiveInfoRef>
        </GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

UPDATE: I was able to get the service to work using the REST implementation but am still curious about the error regarding the SOAP implementation.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the generated XML from your code?

Comment: updated original post with xml sample

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error just adding version parameter to the main request tag in the body: **version="1.0.0"**.

Before:

```
<GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/hotel/descriptiveinfo/v1">
```

After:

```
<GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/hotel/descriptiveinfo/v1">
```

Comment: Even with the version attribute, I can't get it to work. I get `<Message code="ERR.NGHP-CONTENT.SERVICE_NOT_FOUND">Service GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ:GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ:1.0.0 not found</Message>`. I am guessing they either removed the service (for some reason) or changed the version. But the version number is still the same on the doc website. Can you tell me if it's still working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Sabre is extremely disorganized when it comes to keeping any kind of standard throughout their APIs.
That API doesn't accept "service" in the header.

Replace

```
"Service" => "GetHotelDescriptiveInfoRQ",
```

with

```
"Service" => "",
```

in you header.